# T-SQL - Updating a subset of records by Row_Number()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has sub-sets of records for a parent table. 
Each subset has an order stored in a `[rank]` field. 
I need to update this field for a specific subset in this table based on a new order held in the field `otherRank`.

Does the following cover it:

```
update mytable t1 set
[rank] = t2.new_rank_num
from (select t2.id, new_rank_num = row_number() over (order by t2.otherRank)
    from mytable t2 where t2.parentID = 628) t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```

or, would I need:

```
update mytable t1 set
[rank] = t2.new_rank_num
from (select t2.id, new_rank_num = row_number() over (order by t2.otherRank)
    from mytable t2 where t2.parentID = 628) t2
where t1.id = t2.id and t1.parentID = 628
```

My specific issue is I don't want anything to updated outside of the remit of parentID 628

**Edit**
I get an error when trying to run this:

> incorrect syntax near `t1`
>   incorrect syntax near `t2`

so I'm thinking the syntax needs to be:

```
update mytable set
    [rank] = t2.new_rank_num
    from (select id, new_rank_num = row_number() over (order by otherRank)
from mytable where parentID = 628) t2
where id = t2.id and parentID = 628
```

**Edit 2**

OK, I've gone with a CTE Solution for this as recommended by SqlZim.
It looks like this:

```
;with cte as (
  select t2.id, new_rank_num = row_number() over (order by t2.otherRank)
    from mytable t2 where t2.parentID = 628
)

update t1 set 
    [rank] = t2.new_rank_num
from mytable t1
inner join cte t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I've admittedly not tried it yet as I needed some advice on the query syntax primarily.

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the syntax.   If it gives the desired result, go with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to do this sort of thing using a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , new_rank_num = row_number() over (
        partition by ParentId 
        order by otherRank
        )
  from mytable
)
update cte
set [rank] = new_rank_num
where ParentID = 628;
```

If you want to preview the changes before running the update, just change the above to a `select` instead of an `update`. Note that only the first statement after the cte can use the cte.

Comment: thanks I went with a CTE solution - see the question for update

Answer (score 0):

You also can update views, not only tables.

Try this:

```
UPDATE T  
SET [rank] = [new_rank_num]
FROM (
    SELECT 
       [rank]         = [rank], 
       [new_rank_num] = row_number() over (order by otherRank)
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE parentID = 628 
) T
```